# Repetition of the same word in a sentence

Tags: clauses, repetition

**Pouring the water on the flower, Jenny admired the flowers just beginning to open.**

In the above sentence, the word "flower" is repeated once. Is  repetition of the same word in a single sentence ok or is it necessary to avoid repetition?

Comment: This is not a good form of repetition. We need to know what came earlier. What is special about "**the** flower". It must have been mentioned before. Where is Jenny? What has the reader been told about what she has observed or done so far? If we know what came before, we will know how to refer to these other flowers.

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica It is not necessary to know anything about "the flower"; the use of the definite article says that it must be a determinate flower, whatever the particularity (newly acquired specimen, sick plant under "intensive care", …).

Comment: @LPH - I am trying to avoid your phrase ".. among the other ones those ...". It seems very wordy. If we know more, we can suggest a more succinct replacement. Such as, for example, "the ones" or "the others", depending on context.

Comment: @chasly-supportsMonica I can understand trying to get at something concise, but nevertheless the first occurrence of the word has to remain that of a concept used in a determinate way; do you have in mind the replacing of that occurrence with a pronoun? It sounds like an upheaval in the initial construction.

Comment: @LPH - *"do you have in mind the replacing of that occurrence with a pronoun?"* Possibly, e.g. "those", but more likely, one of the two options I gave above, i.e.  "the ones" or "the others" - I understand your concern about a rewrite but, lacking context, we don't even know if a rewrite is advisable or necessary. Context is always good.

Comment: In the phrase it is 'flower' and in the sentence it is flowers. Agreement problem! 2) Two times 'the' in the phrase is not required, as I think.  It can just be 'Pouring water on flowers, Jenny admired them just beginning to open.'

Answer (score 1):

Repetition is sometimes used for special effects but in this sentence this is not the type of repetition that we are dealing with. Good writers will  try to suppress repetition. In this sentence, as the repetition is not exact but is in the plural, it could be preserved without making the sentence really awkward.

- **Pouring the water on the flower, Jenny admired the  flowers just beginning to open.**

Pronouns  can be used instead, but as "just beginning to open" is restrictive (determining, in other words) a different formulation is necessary to preserve this sense. Note that the determining function of "the" in the initial sentence is taken up by "those" in the new sentence.

- **Pouring the water on the flower, Jenny admired *among the other ones those* just beginning to open.**

Comment: It's wordy......"_others just beginning to open"_ would cover it.